# Android - Create new Intent within the same class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I was wondering if anyone had a solution for this. I'm in Activity A and I want to open a new instance for Activity A so I do the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here is the manifest file

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name=".data.App"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=“.controllers.A”
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
       </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hiya Mikerizzo. What's your question, and what happens when you execute your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102337/can-you-have-two-activities-running-at-the-same-time

Comment: It just pops to the same activity thats already on the stack

Comment: @Mikerizzo please post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: You want to create a new instance of this Activity on top of the existing instance so you will then have 2 instances? Please post your manifest entry for this activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

check your `AndroidManifest.xml` , probably your activity has a `launchMode` defined, like `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

**Update:** Your problem is that you are using  `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, delete this property.

Comment: I need to keep the activity open incase the user wants to go back and modify it.

Comment: ok your code us ok, check your activity configuration inside the AndroidManifest.xml...

Comment: android:launchMode="singleTask", delete this property.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to have launchMode = 'standard', I also had some bad logic which is why it looked like it wasn't actually working.

Comment: What was your problem? I am having the same issue, not launch mode set, and I have the flag set on the intent, but it does not load.