# Android Studio: Is it possible to run two activities at once?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-activity

I'm new to programming on Android Studio and am practicing by making an app that uses both the phone's microphone and the Google Maps API. I want the location on the Google Maps Activity to update after a loud noise is heard on the microphone. However, the microphone code/buttons to turn on the microphone are housed in a separate activity. Is it possible to leave the microphone activity one(have a thread run in the activity) while using the Google Maps activity? Or do I have to combine the activities?

Comment: You can use 2 fragments instead of 2 activity. Because your question on title is no.

Comment: `Service` is what you are looking for

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102337/can-you-have-two-activities-running-at-the-same-time ; use thread or fragment or service to run a code (somehow) simultaneous to your activity code.