# How can I show two activities on the same screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I am trying to find a way to show two activities on the same screen, I have two activities main and content activity, the main activity has a mini-player that's implemented and only works in an activity and the content activity has some implementations that also only work in an activity so the solution of converting them into a fragment does not work for me. I need to find a way to show the mini-player in the main activity inside of the content activity. I have looked online and none of the solutions so far have been working for me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you have two activities running at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102337/can-you-have-two-activities-running-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to complete task.

1. Fragments, They can do same things as activity. Its lite weight activity class with more flexible to attach and detach from the screen.
2. Views, If you think your task can be done by only activity then use views for it. you can apply different animations and show/hide feature to display content on the screen within single activity.

[Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) is a part of an activity, which contributes its own UI to that activity. Fragment can be thought like a sub activity. Where as the complete screen with which user interacts is called as activity. An activity can contain multiple fragments.Fragments are mostly a sub part of an activity.

From document

> For example, a news application can use one fragment to show a list of
>   articles on the left and another fragment to display an article on the
>   right—both fragments appear in one activity, side by side, and each
>   fragment has its own set of lifecycle callback methods and handle
>   their own user input events. Thus, instead of using one activity to
>   select an article and another activity to read the article, the user
>   can select an article and read it all within the same activity

Answer (score 0):

At first, Android system can show only one activity on the screen.

You should not use Activity.

Please use [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments). You can use multiple fragment on the same screen.

Comment: what do you mean Android system can only show one activity on the screen ?What if you have a transparent activity on top of another activity?is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragment.Fragment are Runs inside the Activity.
you can display multiple fragment in same time.

Refer [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

[Create a fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating)