# Kotlin Android finish the upper activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am opening two activities at the same time. One is MainActivity and another one is CustomActivity with the button id returnbutton.
I want to close the CustomActivity only by clicking the button and make MainActivity running. I use the code of this.finish() on button clicking but when I click it, my whole app finishes. Someone please help me to finish the CustomActivity only.[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szseY.png)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val intent = Intent(application, CustomActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)


                val button : Button = findViewById(R.id.returnButton)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            this.finish()

        }
```

Comment: Add Logs form the logcat.

Comment: i suggest you look at this -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102337/can-you-have-two-activities-running-at-the-same-time

Comment: Yeah that's not how Activities work, the Button and Finish code needs to be in CustomActivity, you are currently launching CustomActivity and immediately finishing the root Activity, killing the app.

Answer (score 1):

You have button in your **MainActivity**  so when you are using this it is pointing to **MainActivity** and it is closing that activity, I would suggest you to add this Button and its onClick to **CustomActivity**.